# Magento: Disable module for any particular store

Tags: magento-1.9, module, event-observer

Please let me know if you have any solution to disable module and its file for particular store.

I have tried with inchoo (http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-activatedeactivate-magento-module-per-a-website-level/) solution but it is not working while cache is enabled.

Comment: @Raka plz let me know if you got any solution in this.